# Automatically add newly generated component into entryComponents from command line

Tags: angular, typescript, command-line-interface

When creating a new dialog with

```
ng generate component dialog/admin/item/edit-item-dialog
```

is there any way to have it automatically added to the `entryComponents` array inside `app.module.ts`?

It's quite inconvenient to have to open the file every time, scroll through it and place the component inside the array.

---

Specs:

- Angular CLI: 8.0.2
- Node: 10.15.0
- OS: win32 x64
- Angular: 8.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, just read the [docs](https://angular.io/cli/generate#component-command):

```
ng generate component dialog/admin/item/edit-item-dialog --entryComponent=true
```

will automatically place the component inside the `entryComponents` array.